# Get body content and put it into a description text box on a new page using JQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, get, forum

So I have a discussion list(like a forum page) and I have a button on this page that links me to a create a project form. What I want to do is when I click on that button and it opens the form how do I pull the body content from that page (will be the OP post) and then drop it in the description box on the form using JQuery.

Doing this to bypass copying the content clicking the button and then pasting in description. Even if I can figure out how to identify that body content for now. So like a script that gets that content and an alert runs showing me the content.

Thanks

Comment: Add ur relevant code...

Answer (score 0):

get the body html content as follows

```
var bodyhtml = $('body').html();
alert(bodyhtml);
```

this will get all the html tags including the hidden fields if any.

```
 var bodycontent = $('body').text();
 alert(bodycontent );
```

gets the visible string content of the body.

Comment: Ok perfect that worked! Not exactly how I needed it to because maybe its a SharePoint thing but almost there. There is a tag BodyAndMore and I tried that but pulls a blank. This works for the most of it though so I should be able to get going form here. Thanks